# Notify out-of-date buffers in the mode-line

Tags: emacs, modeline

Sometimes I use an alternative method (usually sed) to edit a file
that's already being edited by Emacs. Later, if I try to edit the file
in Emacs without reverting the changes first, I get an error message
and a prompt asking me what to do.

That's all fine. The problem is that I tend to forget very often when
I've made some parallel changes, so I'd like Emacs to
remind me by showing a red "M" in the mode-line.

I know how to customize the mode-line (by adding strings to the
`mode-line-format` variable), but I have no idea how to check if a
file has been modified outside of Emacs.

**Is there a function to check whether an Emacs buffer is up to date
  with the file it corresponds?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(verify-visited-file-modtime (current-buffer))
```

See [Section 27.6 Buffer Modification Time](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Modification-Time.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not really a direct answer to the question, but you can avoid this problem by turning on auto-revert globally in emacs with `(global-auto-revert-mode t)`.